# Extjs and User Authentication and Session

Tags: wcf, extjs

I am planning to use my new project with Sencha Extjs and WCF service.

The only thing I confused is authentication. Do I need to check all ajax call that user session is still valid.

May I know what is the best way to use authentication and user session?

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to check all ajax call that user session is still valid.

Yes you do. Your server side may do it for you though.

> May I know what is the best way to use authentication and user
>   session?

Yes you may. It's all trivial. With every request, AJAX or not, your client side sends session ID to the server. It could be a cookie, a URL param, a field in POST request payload — does not matter. What matters is that the server side needs to have session ID with every request so that it can check if the session is valid, determine who the user is (i.e. authenticate) and allow them to do what they want (i.e. authorise).